# How can i add different images from drawable file in ExpandableListView in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I created a navigation drawer with an expandable listview. Every child item has a textview and an image view. Ever child item has the same image. I want to put different images for every child item. I have an ExpandableListAdapter class. Should i do some changes in  getChildView method of this class? How can i change it? Here is  my ExpandableListAdapter class:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;




public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
        HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData ) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
```

}

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView iconn =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbNail);



   iconn.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_73);

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textView);

    txtListChild.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

   return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Here is activity class of list adapter part:

listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), receivedVal ); // Header, Child data

```
  listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), top250);


  listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

  expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

(receivedVal and top250 are array list and they have values)

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void prepareListData() {
            listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
            listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

            // Adding child data
            listDataHeader.add("imageId1");
            listDataHeader.add("imageId2");
            listDataHeader.add("imageId3");
            listDataHeader.add("imageId4");
            listDataHeader.add("imageId5");
            listDataHeader.add("imageId6");

            // Adding child data
            List<String> Chicken = new ArrayList<String>();
            imageId1.add("imagename");
            imageId1.add("imagename");
            imageMap.put("imageId", R.drawable.imagename)
}
```

Comment: same issue can you check?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431114/how-to-add-image-in-expandablelistivew

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be setting a predefined icon.

```
iconn.setImageResource(mIcons[childPosition]);
iconn.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_73);
```

Removing this line will probably help:

```
iconn.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_73);
```

Comment: don't care about that i forgot this line, i updated my code. My question isn't about that i suppose that i find the solution like that:if(childPosition == 0) {
         iconn.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_48);}  
        
        else if(childPosition == 1){
         iconn.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_49); }

Comment: well forgetting that line means that you will set "R.drawable.car_73" to every child item.

If you have an array of drawables this should work:
    iconn.setImageResource(mIcons[childPosition]);

Comment: you're right. iconn.setImageResource(mIcons[childPosition]);  works. I don't have to do any different implementation. I thought in complex way unnecessarily.

Comment: no problem, please mark the question as answered if this helped you.