# How to add an image to children of an ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, image, expandablelistview

So I have an ExpandableListView with multiple children per group and I want to be able to selectively add a specific image to a particular child of a particular group.

My list_item xml has both a TextView and an ImageView and I currently have every child of every group populating with a single image. However, I can't get over the hurdle of specifying which child gets what image.

My ExpandableListAdapter.java(only relevant code included)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listHashMap) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listHashMap = listHashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);
        }

        ImageView childImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItemImg);
        childImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

My list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:autoLink="web"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItemImg"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried to follow the suggestions here, but I can't get the array[childPosition] to work. What am I missing? [How can i add different images from drawable file in ExpandableListView in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19790762/how-can-i-add-different-images-from-drawable-file-in-expandablelistview-in-andro)

Fairly new to Android development, so thanks for the help.

Comment: make an array of integer with drawable ids with size equal to your child per group in it like image[]={R.drawable.image1,R.drawable.image2, and soon} and set them in your image view from this image array as childImage.setImageResource(image[position])